# Match character not in nested parentheses

Tags: java, regex, parsing

How do you match a character that is not in parentheses? The expression may have an arbitrary number of nested parentheses as well. In other words, I want to split `((2+3)*10)-((10+1)/2)` into `((2+3)*10)` and `((10+1)/2)`. I would like to do this with regular expressions, if possible. I need to know how to do this because I am parsing mathematical-like expressions, so if this is not the way to go, what should I be doing?

I would prefer a solution in java, but if it is in another language I can probably figure it out as well.

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool for this job.  A recursive-descent parser, as others have suggested, may be overkill.  What do you want as the output of the parser?  If you just want to evaluate the expression, a simple state-machine with a pushdown stack will do the job.  If you need to really _parse_ the expression into a syntax tree, then look at [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).  Regardless, you should start out by specifying a complete grammar first.

Comment: I'm developing a programming language, so I'm translating the operators "plus","minus","greater than", etc. to the corresponding symbols in java, but I also have to make sure the types on either side of the operators are valid

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser).  [Here is an article and some example code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/318667/Mathematical-Expression-Parser-Using-Recursive-Des), although the Wikipedia article from the first link has some good example C code.

There are alternatives to a recursive descent parser, such as a [operator-precedence parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser), but my experience from undergrad is with recursive descent parsers (I haven't parsed any mathematical expressions since then).  Either way, you're essentially parsing the mathematical expression in order of operator precedence.

Comment: looks like I need a recursive descent parser, but I can't seem to follow the code on wikipedia and the article. Is there maybe some short pseudocode I can look at to get a feel for how it works? Also, I'm not too well versed in grammars; I can read BNF but I don't understand terminology like LL(k)

Comment: I wish I'd held on to my parser code.  This page has some Java source code that I believe is solving the same problem that you're trying to tackle. http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/CS3723/rdparse/rdparser.html

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a PCRE library for Java.

This feature of PCRE is called RECURSIVE PATTERNS ([See documentation](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt)):

```
$ pcretest                                                                                                                                                                                        
PCRE version 8.31 2012-07-06

  re> / (?: \( (?: [^()]++ | (?R) )* \) ) /xg 
data> ((2+3)*10)-((10+1)/2) 
 0: ((2+3)*10)
 0: ((10+1)/2)
```

I don't know Java, but in PHP it works in this way:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > preg_match_all('/ (?: \( (?: [^()]++ | (?R) )* \) ) /x', '((2+3)*10)-((10+1)/2)', $r); var_dump($r);
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "((2+3)*10)"
    [1]=>
    string(10) "((10+1)/2)"
  }
}
```